# How can I override a value in Java String by a button?

Tags: java, android, xml, string, class

I have two java classes.
"Stickers.java" and "KeyboardService.java".

I have declared a public class string PACK_LIB in "Stickers.java" with the value "".

This string should be overwritten by "KeyboardService.java" from "" into "allstickers" when I click Button "b1".

I linked the classes successfully together but the issue comes that Build Fails with -> error: variable PACK_LIB is already defined in class Stickers
    public String PACK_LIB = "";
                  ^

How can I override this value?

```
-----//Stickers.java

public class Stickers {
    public static String PACK_LIB ="";


    public String PACK_LIB = "";

    public void setDefaultStickerPack() {
        checkVersion(true);
        InputStream in = null;
        String packList[]=new String[0];
        final String PACK_APP="pack_app";
        final String PACK_ICON="pack_on.png";
        String curAssets=""; 
}

-----//KeyboardService.java

public class KeyboardService extends InputMethodService {

 final Button button1 = (Button) mainBoard.findViewById(R.id.b1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Stickers.PACK_LIB = "allstickers";
            }
        });

        final Button button2 = (Button) mainBoard.findViewById((R.id.b2));
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Stickers.PACK_LIB = "teststickers";
            }
        });

}
```

Comment: You have 2 declarations: `public static String PACK_LIB ="";` and `public String PACK_LIB = "";` in the same class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining the PACK_LIB variable two times in Stickers class.

```
public static String PACK_LIB ="";


public String PACK_LIB = "";
```

Remove one of these lines and the error should go.